# How to delete all the files stored in Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() in android

Tags: android

### As the question states:

1. My application has created some files in
   `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`
2. I have to delete all the files of my application in that
   `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` location

***How to do this***

*Note*: It must not delete other files created by other application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `delete()` method on the `File` object for each file to be deleted.

You will need to determine for yourself what files are to be deleted. Nobody else will know, including Android. There is no app-specific ownership information on files on external storage, even if such data would necessarily be reliable for your use case.

Also, bear in mind that each account on Android gets its own part of external storage, and you can only delete files that are in the external storage for whatever account it is that is presently running. Other accounts (on Android 4.2+ tablets and Android 5.0+ phones) are not accessible to you.

Comment: That is why it would have been better to put your application files inside a folder dedicated to your application.

Comment: @CommonsWare ..... Can i use any other place so that android automatically deletes the files insted of using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` which i used

Comment: @Devrath: `getExternalFilesDir()` and `getExternalCacheDir()` on `Context` are the two locations on external storage that will be automatically deleted when the app is uninstalled (or if the user clicks the "Clear Data" button in the app's entry in Settings, though that is not common).

Comment: @Devrath yes you can use `Context.getCacheDir()`. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir(). If you are writing files for cache purposes, you can use that, so that way if the user wants to free up storage and clear cache, they can do so safely. Even the system may clear cache automatically under extreme system pressure. But you should not rely on the system or the user to do that, which is what the doc for `getCacheDir()` says as well.

Comment: @praneetloke: `getFilesDir()` and `getCacheDir()` do get deleted on an uninstall, but they are not on external storage, so the user cannot access the files. `getExternalFilesDir()` and `getExternalCacheDir()` are deleted on uninstall *and* visible to users on external storage.

Comment: @CommonsWare yes I understand. :) However, I was making sure OP isn't going to write cache files to that dir and forget about them. However, if you are writing small cache files (few KBs) then an external cache dir isn't needed as some phones don't have external storage. Besides, OP will need to add the external storage permission and list external storage as a required feature in the manifest if his application must need external storage and cannot work without it.

Comment: @ praneetloke ........ You gave me good input .... Question-1: what happens if i forget it .... would android automatically will delete it ? ............ Question-2: How can i explicitly delete the files programatically(Any stack overflow link for this) :)

Comment: Yes Android will clear the cache if it reaches the threshold. But you should clear those files yourself before it comes to that, by setting a threshold you think you will reach. It depends on the kind of files you are storing I guess. You can delete the files just like in regular Java, using File objects. You can get the directory where you are storing the files and get a list of the files in the directory. Then call `.delete()` on each one of those files.

Comment: Also, note that I said 'cache'. The cache directory is meant for temporary files used by your application. Android will not clear the files stored in `getExternalFilesDir()`. Either of these directories can be cleared out manually by the user though so you can't think that once you write these files that they will remain there forever.